# Laravel livewire: cant detect selected file path

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-livewire

This is my input file field within a form

```
<div class="mb-4">
<label for="exampleFormControlInput32" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Upload file:</label>
<input type="file" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="exampleFormControlInput32" wire:model="file">
@error('file') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
</div>
```

The button execute the store function in controller

```
<button type="button" wire:click.prevent="store()">
                Save
</button>
```

the store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      //validate pdf file and create data in database
        $this->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048',
        ]);
        $session = new Session();
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();
        $request->file->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        Breakdown::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->breakdown_id], [
            'Identification_No' => $session->get('idno'),
            'Breakdown_date' => $this->Breakdown_date,
            'Breakdown_problem' => $this->Breakdown_problem,
            'Breakdown_parts' => $this->Breakdown_parts,
            'Description' => $this->Description,
            'Complete_date' => $this->Complete_date,
            'Action_by' => $this->Action_by,
            'Reviewed_by' => $this->Reviewed_by,
            'Remarks' => $this->Remarks,
            'filename' => $imageName,
        ]);
        session()->flash('message',
            $this->breakdown_id ? 'Breakdown Updated Successfully.' : 'Breakdown Created Successfully.');

        $this->closeModal();
        $this->closeimpModal();
        $this->resetInputFields();


    }
```

However when i tried to upload it, it always pop out this error `Call to a member function extension() on null` at line `$imageName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();`

Comment: Is your store method a method in a Livewire component or a regular controller?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, It is a method in a livewire component.

Comment: Okay. You are using Laravel's built in Http Request class, which is not able to be used when sending requests via Livewire. When selecting a file in your input, it will be saved to your file property you should have defined in your Livewire component, and it is that you must use you go forward with the upload of the file. I recommend you read on Livewire's documentation on file uploading. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads